# Moving folder to same parent returns 400 - Bad Request

Tags: box-api

Attempting to move a folder to the same parent ID returns 400 (Bad Request): "Folder move creates cyclical folder structure."  Is this intended?  It seems like it should effectively be a NOP and return successfully.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the V1 or the V2 api for this?

Comment: V2.  Sorry I didn't see this sooner; I think need to fiddle with my notification settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue. We should be treating this as idempotent and returning a 200. We will be fixing this in the near future.